# How to calculate the milliseconds in Javascript CountUp Timer?

Tags: javascript, math, timer, milliseconds

I found a script that is able to CountUp from a preset date but would like to add miliseconds to it.

What I have right now:

```
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

I can see that milliseconds should look something like this

```
var milliseconds = Math.floor((distance % (****)) / **** );
```

How is it calculated I wonder ?

Edit: I might be not so explicit so here is more of the code ?

The function:

```
var x = setInterval(function(){ ......... }, 1000);
```

Inside the function lies this:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = now - dateCountup;

   ..............



 var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

document.getElementById(".....").innerHTML = ......... + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
```

is distance the milliseconds ?

Comment: Time in JavaScript **is** in milliseconds. Wether you deal with a timestamp, or the delay for setTimeout etc.

Comment: right, thanks, so how do I display the milliseconds as they're being counted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get that using `Date.getTime()`. Use it inside your `setInterval` / `setTimeout`:

```js
var since = new Date("01-01-2020");
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.getTime() - since.getTime() + " ms")

// Assuming you count every 1/100th of a second
setInterval(() => {
  now = new Date();
  console.clear()
  console.log(now.getTime() - since.getTime() + " ms")
}, 10)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I can't seem to get this to work like I want to. It's showing up like this: 6481568ms . Can I reformat it to show .000 milliseconds being counted ?

Comment: @icbxw Edited answer to include a `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks. for some reason the milliseconds are lagging and don't appear as I would want. Any chance to make this work like in this example video: https://streamable.com/jw932 ?

Comment: @icbxw Just change the interval duration, I changed it to 10 ms in my answer

Comment: It took a while, about an hour of fiddling, in the end I changed the function to count every 1/100th of second like so: "setInterval(() { ....... }, 10")" and added milliseconds to the variables: "var milli = Math.floor((distance % 1000) / 1);". Thanks